# Firebase database emulator fails to start with a java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: firebase, testing, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

I have attempted the following

````
$ firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, database, hosting
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: firestore, pubsub
⚠  Your requested "node" version "nodejs10" doesn't match your global version "12"
⚠  database: Did not find a Realtime Database rules file specified in a firebase.json config file. The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration.
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log
⚠  database: Fatal error occurred: 
   Database Emulator has exited with code: 1, 
   stopping all running emulators
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator
⚠  database: Error stopping Database Emulator```
````

Looking at the `database-debug.log` I see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 209
Exception Details:
  Location:
    scala/collection/immutable/HashMap$HashTrieMap.split()Lscala/collection/immutable/Seq; @249: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
[snipped]
```

I'm using Mac OSX. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using an incompatible java version on mac OSX. Using the java runtime from java.com solved the issue.